# IBM WebSphere MQ Overwriting TextMessage Property

Tags: java, properties, ibm-mq

I am setting a Long property on a TextMessage `msg.setLongProperty("publishSequence", pubSeq);`, and sending it to a local IBM WebSphere MQ Queue manager for sending to a remote queue. The message is sending fine, but MQ is removing the Long property when it puts the MQ properties in the message header.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before? And if so, how did you work around it?

Comment: FYI.. I am using the JMS TextMessage object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link was able to answer my question. I have tested and it works.

I used `queue.setMessageBodyStyle(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_JMS);` on the MQQueue object to set the body style to JMS so it would retain the property.

Answer (score 1):

The property you are setting would not map to the message header.  In older versions of WMQ it mapped to an RFH2 header but in newer versions of WMQ (V7.1 and later) the property is accessible using message property setter/getter methods so no RFH2 header would normally be visible.

There is an attribute `PROPCTL` that exists on [queues](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mi203605.htm) and [channels](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mi203606.htm) to control whether you see an RFH2 header.  Depending on how it is set, the properties will not be visible in the payload because no RFH2 header will be produced.  If you set PROPCTL then you can get WMQ to deliver the message with an RFH2 header and you can see the property there. Otherwise you would need to use the property getter methods but won't see the property in the message header in any case since it is not one that is mapped there.

Please see the Infocenter topic [*Mapping JMS fields onto WebSphere MQ fields (outgoing messages)*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm25460_.htm) for more info.

Comment: When receiving the message, I am trying to get the property via getLongProperty and it doesn't exist. I tried reading up on your explanation, and I am still at a loss on what to do.

Comment: When you set the property, are you catching MessageNotWriteableException and JMSException? An unhandled exception might allow the property set to fail but still write the message. Have you tried to retrieve the properties on the local QMgr? The properties might be converted to RFH2 in the channel or on the remote queue. Retrieving them locally would eliminate these points of failure from the equation.

Comment: I found a link that might work for what I need: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21573858. I will test it tonight in my testing window, and return with my results.